# How does sensation contribute to empirical intuition and empirical concept?

Tags: kant, perception

I have been reading about Kant's theory of cognition in this article https://www.iep.utm.edu/kantmind/#SH2d. This is an extract that I have been trying to  understand :

> "The genus is representation (representatio) in general. Under it stand representations with consciousness (perceptio). A perception [Wahrnehmung], that relates solely to a subject as a modification of its state, is sensation (sensatio). An objective perception is cognition (cognitio). This is either intuition or concept (intuitus vel conceptus). The first relates immediately to the object and is singular; the second is mediate, conveyed by a mark, which can be common to many things. A concept is either an empirical or a pure concept, and the pure concept, insofar as it has its origin solely in the understanding (not in a pure image of sensibility), is called notio. A concept made up of notions, which goes beyond the possibility of experience, is an idea or a concept of reason. (A320/B376–7)."

I do not understand how sensation (which is subjective) related to empirical intuition and concept (which come under cognition and which in turn is objective). I came to know of this relation from this diagram.

[image]

Comment: "Sensations" are the raw material to be organized by forms of intuition and concepts. It is the organizing process that "extracts" the objective out of them.

Comment: Where did you find this diagram? Kant's epistemplogy is very complex and a random book might simply have it wrong and offer confusing advice. Thanks.

Comment: @user3451767 I found the diagram in wikipedia. Does it not provide the full picture?

Comment: @erif tsalb Hard to tell. As useful as Wikipedia is in many areas of knowledge, Kant's epistemology is so complicated and so controversly interpreted that I would be highly suspicious when it comes to diagrams which are not produced by a high level researcher in the field. I have read Kant in German -- maybe I will have time to produce some sort of an answer later.

Answer (score -2):

Empirical evidence is the information received by means of the senses, particularly by observation and ... and interpretation, scientists may still disagree on the nature of ...an empirical evidence, is whats gathered by testing.  Empirical Intuition: Wholly contingent sense perception of a single object. Pure Intuition: Object necessarily joined to all empirical intuitions in advance of any particular perceptions. There are two pure intuitions: space and time.
Sensory- contributes?>/inside car-driving it ,,nessesity example:?'s trying to daydream without a brain.